# hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin generates source code for an xsd file but doesn't annotate all elements in ObjectFactory with XmlElementDecl

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Here's([onvif.xsd](https://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd)) the schema file I'm trying to generate the source code for, using hisrc-higherjaxb.

Here's part of my pom.xml configuration,

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>onvif-onvif-xsd</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-no-header</arg>
                    <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                </args>

                <generatePackage></generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <episode>true</episode>
                <episodeFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/episodes/onvif.episode
                </episodeFile>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <enableExternalEntityProcessing>true</enableExternalEntityProcessing>
                <bindings></bindings>
                <strict>false</strict>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <disableXmlSecurity>true</disableXmlSecurity>

                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The code generates fine with all the types declared in the schema. The generated ObjectFactory defines factory methods for all types but annotates only some methods with XmlElementDecl. Due to this, my marshaller is unable to unmarshal these unannotated elements, when they appear in place of xs:any(with processContents="lax") elements, and leaves them out as dom elements as they haven't been declared in the namespace.

How do I get it to annotate all factory methods?

Answer (score 1):

The XJC tool ([JAXB RI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/tree/4.0.2-RI-RELEASE/jaxb-ri)) is responsible for generating the `XmlElementDecl` annotations and it conforms to the [JAXB API](https://github.com/jakartaee/jaxb-api/tree/4.0.0-RELEASE). The [hisrc-higherjaxb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) Maven plugin configures and invokes the XJC tool.

Below is the list of the all Java classes generated by XJC for the `"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"` schema. Two of the Java types are root elements (`XmlRootElement`). Sixteen of the types are wrapped in JAXB elements (`XmlElementDecl`) and the rest [452] are complex types. A good article explaining how XJC generates the annotations is at [JAXB and Root Elements](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).

In a nutshell, the list identifies these three groups:

- RE: XML schema root elements declared with an anonymous complex type.
- JE: XML schema JAXB elements declared with a named complex type.
- CT: XML schema complex types without an element binding.

The `ObjectFactory` does not declare JAXB elements (`XmlElementDecl`) for the classes marked with `CT`. For example, the `User` type is generated from an XML schema `complexType` without a corresponding `element` binding. If you add this binding:

**onvif.xsd**

```
<xs:element name="User" type="tt:User"/>
```

Then XJC will generate this `XmlElementDecl` in the `ObjectFactory`:

```
...
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema", name = "User")
public JAXBElement<User> createUser(User value) {
    return new JAXBElement<>(_User_QNAME, User.class, null, value);
}
...
```

**ComplexType vs JAXBElement vs RootElement**

```
|Group |Package: org.onvif.ver10.schema               |
|:----:|----------------------------------------------|
|  CT  |AACDecOptions                                 |
|  CT  |AbsoluteFocus                                 |
|  CT  |AbsoluteFocusOptions                          |
|  CT  |ActionEngineEventPayload                      |
|  CT  |ActionEngineEventPayloadExtension             |
|  CT  |ActiveConnection                              |
|  CT  |AnalyticsCapabilities                         |
|  CT  |AnalyticsDeviceCapabilities                   |
|  CT  |AnalyticsDeviceEngineConfiguration            |
|  CT  |AnalyticsDeviceEngineConfigurationExtension   |
|  CT  |AnalyticsDeviceExtension                      |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngine                               |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngineConfiguration                  |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngineConfigurationExtension         |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngineControl                        |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngineInput                          |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngineInputInfo                      |
|  CT  |AnalyticsEngineInputInfoExtension             |
|  CT  |AnalyticsState                                |
|  CT  |AnalyticsStateInformation                     |
|  CT  |AnyHolder                                     |
|  CT  |ArrayOfFileProgress                           |
|  CT  |ArrayOfFileProgressExtension                  |
|  CT  |AttachmentData                                |
|  CT  |AudioAttributes                               |
|  CT  |AudioClassCandidate                           |
|  CT  |AudioClassDescriptor                          |
|  CT  |AudioClassDescriptorExtension                 |
|  JE  |AudioDecoderConfiguration                     |
|  CT  |AudioDecoderConfigurationOptions              |
|  CT  |AudioDecoderConfigurationOptionsExtension     |
|  CT  |AudioEncoder2Configuration                    |
|  CT  |AudioEncoder2ConfigurationOptions             |
|  JE  |AudioEncoderConfiguration                     |
|  CT  |AudioEncoderConfigurationOption               |
|  CT  |AudioEncoderConfigurationOptions              |
|  CT  |AudioOutput                                   |
|  JE  |AudioOutputConfiguration                      |
|  CT  |AudioOutputConfigurationOptions               |
|  CT  |AudioSource                                   |
|  JE  |AudioSourceConfiguration                      |
|  CT  |AudioSourceConfigurationOptions               |
|  CT  |AudioSourceOptionsExtension                   |
|  CT  |BacklightCompensation                         |
|  CT  |BacklightCompensation20                       |
|  CT  |BacklightCompensationOptions                  |
|  CT  |BacklightCompensationOptions20                |
|  CT  |BackupFile                                    |
|  CT  |BinaryData                                    |
|  CT  |Capabilities                                  |
|  CT  |CapabilitiesExtension                         |
|  CT  |CapabilitiesExtension2                        |
|  CT  |CellLayout                                    |
|  CT  |Certificate                                   |
|  CT  |CertificateGenerationParameters               |
|  CT  |CertificateGenerationParametersExtension      |
|  CT  |CertificateInformation                        |
|  CT  |CertificateInformationExtension               |
|  CT  |CertificateStatus                             |
|  CT  |CertificateUsage                              |
|  CT  |CertificateWithPrivateKey                     |
|  CT  |CodingCapabilities                            |
|  CT  |Color                                         |
|  CT  |ColorCovariance                               |
|  CT  |ColorDescriptor                               |
|  CT  |ColorOptions                                  |
|  CT  |ColorspaceRange                               |
|  CT  |Config                                        |
|  CT  |ConfigDescription                             |
|  CT  |ConfigDescriptionExtension                    |
|  CT  |ConfigurationEntity                           |
|  CT  |ContinuousFocus                               |
|  CT  |ContinuousFocusOptions                        |
|  CT  |Date                                          |
|  CT  |DateTime                                      |
|  CT  |DateTimeRange                                 |
|  CT  |Defogging                                     |
|  CT  |DefoggingExtension                            |
|  CT  |DefoggingOptions                              |
|  CT  |DeviceCapabilities                            |
|  CT  |DeviceCapabilitiesExtension                   |
|  CT  |DeviceEntity                                  |
|  CT  |DeviceIOCapabilities                          |
|  CT  |DigitalInput                                  |
|  CT  |DisplayCapabilities                           |
|  CT  |DNSInformation                                |
|  CT  |DNSInformationExtension                       |
|  CT  |Dot11AvailableNetworks                        |
|  CT  |Dot11AvailableNetworksExtension               |
|  CT  |Dot11Capabilities                             |
|  CT  |Dot11Configuration                            |
|  CT  |Dot11PSKSet                                   |
|  CT  |Dot11PSKSetExtension                          |
|  CT  |Dot11SecurityConfiguration                    |
|  CT  |Dot11SecurityConfigurationExtension           |
|  CT  |Dot11Status                                   |
|  CT  |Dot1XConfiguration                            |
|  CT  |Dot1XConfigurationExtension                   |
|  CT  |Dot3Configuration                             |
|  JE  |DurationRange                                 |
|  CT  |DynamicDNSInformation                         |
|  CT  |DynamicDNSInformationExtension                |
|  CT  |EAPMethodConfiguration                        |
|  CT  |EapMethodExtension                            |
|  CT  |EFlip                                         |
|  CT  |EFlipOptions                                  |
|  CT  |EFlipOptionsExtension                         |
|  CT  |EngineConfiguration                           |
|  CT  |EventCapabilities                             |
|  CT  |EventFilter                                   |
|  CT  |EventSubscription                             |
|  CT  |Exposure                                      |
|  CT  |Exposure20                                    |
|  CT  |ExposureOptions                               |
|  CT  |ExposureOptions20                             |
|  CT  |FileProgress                                  |
|  CT  |FindEventResult                               |
|  CT  |FindEventResultList                           |
|  CT  |FindMetadataResult                            |
|  CT  |FindMetadataResultList                        |
|  CT  |FindPTZPositionResult                         |
|  CT  |FindPTZPositionResultList                     |
|  CT  |FindRecordingResultList                       |
|  CT  |FloatItems                                    |
|  JE  |FloatRange                                    |
|  CT  |FocusConfiguration                            |
|  CT  |FocusConfiguration20                          |
|  CT  |FocusConfiguration20Extension                 |
|  CT  |FocusMove                                     |
|  CT  |FocusOptions                                  |
|  CT  |FocusOptions20                                |
|  CT  |FocusOptions20Extension                       |
|  CT  |FocusStatus                                   |
|  CT  |FocusStatus20                                 |
|  CT  |FocusStatus20Extension                        |
|  CT  |G711DecOptions                                |
|  CT  |G726DecOptions                                |
|  CT  |GenericEapPwdConfigurationExtension           |
|  CT  |GeoLocation                                   |
|  CT  |GeoOrientation                                |
|  CT  |GetRecordingJobsResponseItem                  |
|  CT  |GetRecordingsResponseItem                     |
|  CT  |GetTracksResponseItem                         |
|  CT  |GetTracksResponseList                         |
|  CT  |H264Configuration                             |
|  CT  |H264DecOptions                                |
|  CT  |H264Options                                   |
|  CT  |H264Options2                                  |
|  CT  |HostnameInformation                           |
|  CT  |HostnameInformationExtension                  |
|  CT  |ImageStabilization                            |
|  CT  |ImageStabilizationExtension                   |
|  CT  |ImageStabilizationOptions                     |
|  CT  |ImageStabilizationOptionsExtension            |
|  CT  |ImagingCapabilities                           |
|  CT  |ImagingOptions                                |
|  CT  |ImagingOptions20                              |
|  CT  |ImagingOptions20Extension                     |
|  CT  |ImagingOptions20Extension2                    |
|  CT  |ImagingOptions20Extension3                    |
|  CT  |ImagingOptions20Extension4                    |
|  CT  |ImagingSettings                               |
|  CT  |ImagingSettings20                             |
|  CT  |ImagingSettingsExtension                      |
|  CT  |ImagingSettingsExtension20                    |
|  CT  |ImagingSettingsExtension202                   |
|  CT  |ImagingSettingsExtension203                   |
|  CT  |ImagingSettingsExtension204                   |
|  CT  |ImagingStatus                                 |
|  CT  |ImagingStatus20                               |
|  CT  |ImagingStatus20Extension                      |
|  CT  |IntItems                                      |
|  JE  |IntRange                                      |
|  CT  |IntRectangle                                  |
|  JE  |IntRectangleRange                             |
|  CT  |IOCapabilities                                |
|  CT  |IOCapabilitiesExtension                       |
|  CT  |IOCapabilitiesExtension2                      |
|  CT  |IPAddress                                     |
|  CT  |IPAddressFilter                               |
|  CT  |IPAddressFilterExtension                      |
|  CT  |IPv4Configuration                             |
|  CT  |IPv4NetworkInterface                          |
|  CT  |IPv4NetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration          |
|  CT  |IPv6Configuration                             |
|  CT  |IPv6ConfigurationExtension                    |
|  CT  |IPv6NetworkInterface                          |
|  CT  |IPv6NetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration          |
|  CT  |IrCutFilterAutoAdjustment                     |
|  CT  |IrCutFilterAutoAdjustmentExtension            |
|  CT  |IrCutFilterAutoAdjustmentOptions              |
|  CT  |IrCutFilterAutoAdjustmentOptionsExtension     |
|  CT  |ItemList                                      |
|  CT  |ItemListDescription                           |
|  CT  |ItemListDescriptionExtension                  |
|  CT  |ItemListExtension                             |
|  CT  |JpegDecOptions                                |
|  CT  |JpegOptions                                   |
|  CT  |JpegOptions2                                  |
|  CT  |Layout                                        |
|  CT  |LayoutExtension                               |
|  CT  |LayoutOptions                                 |
|  CT  |LayoutOptionsExtension                        |
|  CT  |LensDescription                               |
|  CT  |LensOffset                                    |
|  CT  |LensProjection                                |
|  CT  |LocalLocation                                 |
|  CT  |LocalOrientation                              |
|  CT  |LocationEntity                                |
|  CT  |MaximumNumberOfOSDs                           |
|  CT  |MediaAttributes                               |
|  CT  |MediaCapabilities                             |
|  CT  |MediaCapabilitiesExtension                    |
|  CT  |MediaUri                                      |
|  RE  |Message                                       |
|  CT  |MessageDescription                            |
|  CT  |MessageDescriptionExtension                   |
|  CT  |MessageExtension                              |
|  CT  |MetadataAttributes                            |
|  JE  |MetadataConfiguration                         |
|  CT  |MetadataConfigurationExtension                |
|  CT  |MetadataConfigurationOptions                  |
|  CT  |MetadataConfigurationOptionsExtension         |
|  CT  |MetadataConfigurationOptionsExtension2        |
|  CT  |MetadataFilter                                |
|  CT  |MetadataInput                                 |
|  CT  |MetadataInputExtension                        |
|  CT  |MotionExpression                              |
|  CT  |MotionExpressionConfiguration                 |
|  CT  |MoveOptions                                   |
|  CT  |MoveOptions20                                 |
|  CT  |Mpeg4Configuration                            |
|  CT  |Mpeg4DecOptions                               |
|  CT  |Mpeg4Options                                  |
|  CT  |Mpeg4Options2                                 |
|  CT  |MulticastConfiguration                        |
|  CT  |NetworkCapabilities                           |
|  CT  |NetworkCapabilitiesExtension                  |
|  CT  |NetworkCapabilitiesExtension2                 |
|  CT  |NetworkGateway                                |
|  CT  |NetworkHost                                   |
|  CT  |NetworkHostExtension                          |
|  CT  |NetworkInterface                              |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceConnectionSetting             |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceExtension                     |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceExtension2                    |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceInfo                          |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceLink                          |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration              |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceSetConfigurationExtension     |
|  CT  |NetworkInterfaceSetConfigurationExtension2    |
|  CT  |NetworkProtocol                               |
|  CT  |NetworkProtocolExtension                      |
|  CT  |NetworkZeroConfiguration                      |
|  CT  |NetworkZeroConfigurationExtension             |
|  CT  |NetworkZeroConfigurationExtension2            |
|  CT  |NoiseReduction                                |
|  CT  |NoiseReductionOptions                         |
|  CT  |NTPInformation                                |
|  CT  |NTPInformationExtension                       |
|  CT  |ObjectFactory                                 |
|  CT  |OnvifVersion                                  |
|  CT  |OSDColor                                      |
|  CT  |OSDColorOptions                               |
|  CT  |OSDColorOptionsExtension                      |
|  CT  |OSDConfiguration                              |
|  CT  |OSDConfigurationExtension                     |
|  CT  |OSDConfigurationOptions                       |
|  CT  |OSDConfigurationOptionsExtension              |
|  CT  |OSDImgConfiguration                           |
|  CT  |OSDImgConfigurationExtension                  |
|  CT  |OSDImgOptions                                 |
|  CT  |OSDImgOptionsExtension                        |
|  CT  |OSDPosConfiguration                           |
|  CT  |OSDPosConfigurationExtension                  |
|  CT  |OSDReference                                  |
|  CT  |OSDTextConfiguration                          |
|  CT  |OSDTextConfigurationExtension                 |
|  CT  |OSDTextOptions                                |
|  CT  |OSDTextOptionsExtension                       |
|  CT  |PaneConfiguration                             |
|  CT  |PaneLayout                                    |
|  CT  |PaneLayoutOptions                             |
|  CT  |PaneOptionExtension                           |
|  CT  |PanTiltLimits                                 |
|  JE  |Polygon                                       |
|  JE  |PolygonOptions                                |
|  JE  |Polyline                                      |
|  CT  |PolylineArray                                 |
|  CT  |PolylineArrayConfiguration                    |
|  CT  |PolylineArrayExtension                        |
|  CT  |PrefixedIPv4Address                           |
|  CT  |PrefixedIPv6Address                           |
|  CT  |PresetTour                                    |
|  CT  |Profile                                       |
|  CT  |ProfileCapabilities                           |
|  CT  |ProfileExtension                              |
|  CT  |ProfileExtension2                             |
|  CT  |ProfileStatus                                 |
|  CT  |ProfileStatusExtension                        |
|  CT  |PTControlDirection                            |
|  CT  |PTControlDirectionExtension                   |
|  CT  |PTControlDirectionOptions                     |
|  CT  |PTControlDirectionOptionsExtension            |
|  CT  |PTZCapabilities                               |
|  JE  |PTZConfiguration                              |
|  CT  |PTZConfigurationExtension                     |
|  CT  |PTZConfigurationExtension2                    |
|  CT  |PTZConfigurationOptions                       |
|  CT  |PTZConfigurationOptions2                      |
|  CT  |PTZFilter                                     |
|  CT  |PTZMoveStatus                                 |
|  CT  |PTZNode                                       |
|  CT  |PTZNodeExtension                              |
|  CT  |PTZNodeExtension2                             |
|  CT  |PTZPositionFilter                             |
|  CT  |PTZPreset                                     |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourExtension                        |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourOptions                          |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourPresetDetail                     |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourPresetDetailOptions              |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourPresetDetailOptionsExtension     |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourSpot                             |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourSpotExtension                    |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourSpotOptions                      |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourStartingCondition                |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourStartingConditionExtension       |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourStartingConditionOptions         |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourStartingConditionOptionsExtension|
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourStatus                           |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourStatusExtension                  |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourSupported                        |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourSupportedExtension               |
|  CT  |PTZPresetTourTypeExtension                    |
|  CT  |PTZSpaces                                     |
|  CT  |PTZSpacesExtension                            |
|  CT  |PTZSpeed                                      |
|  CT  |PTZStatus                                     |
|  CT  |PTZStatusFilterOptions                        |
|  CT  |PTZStatusFilterOptionsExtension               |
|  CT  |PTZVector                                     |
|  CT  |RealTimeStreamingCapabilities                 |
|  CT  |RealTimeStreamingCapabilitiesExtension        |
|  CT  |Receiver                                      |
|  CT  |ReceiverCapabilities                          |
|  CT  |ReceiverConfiguration                         |
|  CT  |ReceiverStateInformation                      |
|  CT  |RecordingCapabilities                         |
|  CT  |RecordingConfiguration                        |
|  CT  |RecordingEncryption                           |
|  CT  |RecordingEventFilter                          |
|  CT  |RecordingInformation                          |
|  CT  |RecordingJobConfiguration                     |
|  CT  |RecordingJobConfigurationExtension            |
|  CT  |RecordingJobSource                            |
|  CT  |RecordingJobSourceExtension                   |
|  CT  |RecordingJobStateInformation                  |
|  CT  |RecordingJobStateInformationExtension         |
|  CT  |RecordingJobStateSource                       |
|  CT  |RecordingJobStateTrack                        |
|  CT  |RecordingJobStateTracks                       |
|  CT  |RecordingJobTrack                             |
|  CT  |RecordingSourceInformation                    |
|  CT  |RecordingSummary                              |
|  CT  |RecordingTargetConfiguration                  |
|  CT  |Rectangle                                     |
|  CT  |RelativeFocus                                 |
|  CT  |RelativeFocusOptions                          |
|  CT  |RelativeFocusOptions20                        |
|  CT  |RelayOutput                                   |
|  CT  |RelayOutputSettings                           |
|  CT  |RemoteUser                                    |
|  CT  |ReplayCapabilities                            |
|  CT  |ReplayConfiguration                           |
|  CT  |Reverse                                       |
|  CT  |ReverseOptions                                |
|  CT  |ReverseOptionsExtension                       |
|  CT  |Rotate                                        |
|  CT  |RotateExtension                               |
|  CT  |RotateOptions                                 |
|  CT  |RotateOptionsExtension                        |
|  CT  |RuleEngineConfiguration                       |
|  CT  |RuleEngineConfigurationExtension              |
|  CT  |SceneOrientation                              |
|  CT  |Scope                                         |
|  CT  |SearchCapabilities                            |
|  CT  |SearchScope                                   |
|  CT  |SearchScopeExtension                          |
|  CT  |SecurityCapabilities                          |
|  CT  |SecurityCapabilitiesExtension                 |
|  CT  |SecurityCapabilitiesExtension2                |
|  CT  |SourceIdentification                          |
|  CT  |SourceIdentificationExtension                 |
|  CT  |SourceReference                               |
|  CT  |Space1DDescription                            |
|  CT  |Space2DDescription                            |
|  CT  |SphericalCoordinate                           |
|  CT  |StorageReferencePath                          |
|  CT  |StorageReferencePathExtension                 |
|  CT  |StreamSetup                                   |
|  RE  |StringItems                                   |
|  CT  |SupportedAnalyticsModules                     |
|  CT  |SupportedAnalyticsModulesExtension            |
|  CT  |SupportedRules                                |
|  CT  |SupportedRulesExtension                       |
|  CT  |SupportInformation                            |
|  CT  |SystemCapabilities                            |
|  CT  |SystemCapabilitiesExtension                   |
|  CT  |SystemCapabilitiesExtension2                  |
|  CT  |SystemDateTime                                |
|  CT  |SystemDateTimeExtension                       |
|  CT  |SystemLog                                     |
|  CT  |SystemLogUri                                  |
|  CT  |SystemLogUriList                              |
|  CT  |Time                                          |
|  CT  |TimeZone                                      |
|  CT  |TLSConfiguration                              |
|  CT  |ToneCompensation                              |
|  CT  |ToneCompensationExtension                     |
|  CT  |ToneCompensationOptions                       |
|  CT  |TrackAttributes                               |
|  CT  |TrackAttributesExtension                      |
|  CT  |TrackConfiguration                            |
|  CT  |TrackInformation                              |
|  CT  |Transformation                                |
|  CT  |TransformationExtension                       |
|  CT  |Transport                                     |
|  CT  |User                                          |
|  CT  |UserExtension                                 |
|  CT  |Vector                                        |
|  CT  |Vector1D                                      |
|  CT  |Vector2D                                      |
|  JE  |VideoAnalyticsConfiguration                   |
|  CT  |VideoAttributes                               |
|  CT  |VideoDecoderConfigurationOptions              |
|  CT  |VideoDecoderConfigurationOptionsExtension     |
|  CT  |VideoEncoder2Configuration                    |
|  CT  |VideoEncoder2ConfigurationOptions             |
|  JE  |VideoEncoderConfiguration                     |
|  CT  |VideoEncoderConfigurationOptions              |
|  CT  |VideoEncoderOptionsExtension                  |
|  CT  |VideoEncoderOptionsExtension2                 |
|  CT  |VideoOutput                                   |
|  CT  |VideoOutputConfiguration                      |
|  CT  |VideoOutputConfigurationOptions               |
|  CT  |VideoOutputExtension                          |
|  CT  |VideoRateControl                              |
|  CT  |VideoRateControl2                             |
|  CT  |VideoResolution                               |
|  CT  |VideoResolution2                              |
|  CT  |VideoSource                                   |
|  JE  |VideoSourceConfiguration                      |
|  CT  |VideoSourceConfigurationExtension             |
|  CT  |VideoSourceConfigurationExtension2            |
|  CT  |VideoSourceConfigurationOptions               |
|  CT  |VideoSourceConfigurationOptionsExtension      |
|  CT  |VideoSourceConfigurationOptionsExtension2     |
|  CT  |VideoSourceExtension                          |
|  CT  |VideoSourceExtension2                         |
|  CT  |WhiteBalance                                  |
|  CT  |WhiteBalance20                                |
|  CT  |WhiteBalance20Extension                       |
|  CT  |WhiteBalanceOptions                           |
|  CT  |WhiteBalanceOptions20                         |
|  CT  |WhiteBalanceOptions20Extension                |
|  CT  |WideDynamicRange                              |
|  CT  |WideDynamicRange20                            |
|  CT  |WideDynamicRangeOptions                       |
|  CT  |WideDynamicRangeOptions20                     |
|  CT  |ZoomLimits                                    |
```